# Python variable between if and elif

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

The following is invalid syntax as the `elif` needs to be right after the `if` block:

```
def get_number(self, bsObj):
    temp = self.get_data('text1', bsObj)
    if temp > -1:
        return temp
    temp = self.get_info('text', bsObj)
    elif temp > -1:
        return temp
    else:
        return 0
```

I only want to return the result of `self.get_info('text', bsObj)` if `self.get_data('text1', bsObj)` is less than -1.

I could fix it by doing this, but it seems very ineffective to call the same function twice:

```
def get_number(self, bsObj):
    if self.get_data('text1', bsObj) > -1:
        return self.get_data('text1', bsObj)
    elif self.get_info('text', bsObj) > -1:
        return self.get_data('text', bsObj)
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: The whole point of functions is just that though

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered below. I now know that I missed something very important about what the return statement does. I mistakenly thought that if both if statementa were True the first return statement would be replaced by the second. I feel really dumb now, but I'm also very happy that I now learned this very important point. It will really make coding much simpler for me now. So thank you to all of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **use a second `if`**:

```
def get_number(self, bsObj):
    temp = self.get_data('text1', bsObj)
    if temp > -1:
        return temp
    temp = self.get_info('text', bsObj)
    if temp > -1:
        return temp
    else:
        return 0
```

Since the first `if` **contains a return statement**, the interpreter will never reach your `elif` line if the constraint is satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `if` instead of `elif`. The `el[se]` is redundant because of the `return` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `return` exits the function, so you don't have to worry about your branch logic.  You're correct that you shouldn't call a function twice: continue to use `temp` for each call.

You have two choices.  The first is to simply use a new `if`; the old one already left the function.

```
temp = self.get_data('text1', bsObj)
if temp > -1:
    return temp

temp = self.get_info('text', bsObj)
if temp > -1:
    return temp

return 0
```

The other choice is to correctly wrap the "else" logic in that block:

```
temp = self.get_data('text1', bsObj)
if temp > -1:
    return temp
else:
    temp = self.get_info('text', bsObj)
    if temp > -1:
        return temp
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def get_number(self, bsObj):
    temp = self.get_data('text1', bsObj)
    if temp < -1:
        temp = self.get_info('text', bsObj)
    elif temp = -1:
        return 0
    else:
        pass
    return temp
```

So what I've done is switched your if and elif cases. You only want to change your temp definition if temp < -1, and if temp = -1. (really, even the pass is a little redundant, if you don't want to keep it you should be able to get rid of it just fine.)

Answer (score 1):

Written in a more concise way:

```
def get_number(self, bsObj):
    temp = self.get_data('text1', bsObj) if self.get_data('text1', bsObj)>-1 else self.get_info('text', bsObj)
    return temp if temp>-1 else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works, but I decided to post this for fun.

```
def get_number(self, bsObj):
    temp = self.get_data('text1', bsObj)
    temp2 = self.get_info('text', bsObj)
    return temp if temp > -1 else temp2 if temp2 > -1 else 0
```

Comment: Note that `get_info` is being called, regardless of the value of `self.get_data('text1', bsObj)`, where in the original code, it does not

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. Efficiency though is relative to whether or not `self.get_info()` will be called often or not every time `get_number()` is called. We do not know the answer to that.